# Use a reference inside an ArrayList to call a method, and change the current state of the referenced object?

Tags: java, reference, arraylist

Maybe this just isn't possible but what I'm trying to do is change the visibility of multiple elements in a GUI at the same time using an ArrayList to reference to them sort of dynamically. The objects are created by themselves in another method.

Both **oldScreen.setVisible(false);** and **oldScreen<1>.setVisible(false);** statements cause errors. I had a hunch my idea wouldn't work out so well.

Here is basically what i have, any way i can achieve this?

```
private void initScreens() {
// I create some ArrayLists as "screensets" of sorts and put some GUI elements in there
    ArrayList startScreen = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList lostScreen = new ArrayList();
    ArrayList playScreen = new ArrayList();
    startScreen.add(startB);
    startScreen.add(exitB);

    lostScreen.add(yl1);
    lostScreen.add(yl2);
    lostScreen.add(yl3);
    lostScreen.add(yl4);
    lostScreen.add(yl5);


}
private void changeScreen(ArrayList oldScreen,ArrayList newScreen) {
// now i try to create a handy method to handle the length of the arrays itself, so if
i need to make changes to screens I just add them to there array. They are then easily
displayed, and hidden when told.

    int os = oldScreen.size();
    int ns = newScreen.size();

    for (int i = os; i > 0; i--){
        oldScreen<i>.setVisible(false);
        oldScreen<1>.setVisible(false);
    }
```

Comment: Also your ``for`` loop is not correct: the index starts at ``0`` and ends at ``size - 1``. The usual idiom is: ``for(int i = 0 ; i < size ; ++i)``. In addition, your ``oldScreen.get(1).setVisible(false);`` should be outside the loop (or even removed since the index is included in your loop!): you do not want to execute it ``size`` times!

Comment: What does 'statements cause errors' exactly mean? Replace `oldScreen<i>` with `oldScreen[i]`...

Comment: yea i figured it out actually pretty quick that my syntax wasn't correct. Really hate it when its that simple, but thanks! and i did know that referencing i in the oldScreen then 1 was redundant but that was just saying i tried both, really shouldn't matter but i included it anyways.

Answer (score 2):

That's invalid syntax.

You're trying to write

```
oldScreen.get(i)
```

You should also use generics (`ArrayList<Screen>`) to avoid casting.